# Ansible create template in loop with access to item

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm trying to dynamically create a new nginx host for each item found in an array. However, I need to know the details of the loop.

```
- name: 'adding sites to nginx'
  template:
    src: 'nginx/template.conf.j2'
    dest: '/etc/nginx/conf.d/{{ item }}.conf'
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    mode: 0644
  with_items:
    - '{{ sites }}'
```

This works perfectly, with the exception that the template doesn't have access to the loop data. (sites) I need to know the site so I can properly generate the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to gain access by using `{{ item }}` instead of `{{ sites }}`.

```
- name: 'adding sites to nginx'
  template:
    src: 'nginx/template.conf.j2'
    dest: '/etc/nginx/conf.d/{{ item }}.conf'
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    mode: 0644
  with_items:
    - '{{ sites }}'
```

Then within `template.conf.j2`, you can access the current loop by targetting `{{ item }}`

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name {{ item }}.{{ domain }};
  set $base {{ app_path }}/{{ item }};
  root $base/public;

  # SSL
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ domain }}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/{{ domain }}/privkey.pem;
}
```